# Eliminating arrows from a factor analysis Biplot {psych} in R

Tags: r, factor-analysis

In the `biplot` produced by the following code I am trying to get rid of the red lines. I would appreciate it if anyone could help.

```
library(psych)
data(bfi)
fa2 <- fa(bfi[16:25],2)  #factor analysis
fa2$scores <- fa2$scores[1:100,]  #just take the first 100
biplot(fa2,pch=c(24,21)[bfi[1:100,"gender"]],bg=c("blue","red")[bfi[1:100,"gender"]],
main="Biplot of Conscientiousness and Neuroticism by gender")
```

[image]

Comment: Did you look at the `biplot` help page? Seems like `var.axes = FALSE` might be an obvious candidate.

Comment: I did and I expected it to work but it did not / or I am missing sth.

Comment: Well, please update your question to include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Since there is no sample data, we can't run the exact same command and get the same result so it's difficult to help.

Comment: I am really sorry...the first line which indicates the dataset was missing. My bad. just edited the code.

Comment: Given that there are _at least_ *nine* different packages (and stats has two differnt ones) with a function named `biplot` you could at least offer some context.

Comment: Thanks Just added the package's name into the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever reason, the `psych` library decided to re-write it's own biplot so it ignores many of the standard parameters. You can create your own version and just remove the arrow drawing. This method is somewhat hacky but tested with `psych_1.4.5`. Just verify that

```
body(biplot.psych)[[c(11,3,12)]]
```

returns

```
arrows(0, 0, x$loadings[, 1L] * 0.8, x$loadings[, 2L] * 0.8, 
    col = col[2L], length = arrow.len)
```

to make sure we are changing the correct line. Then you can do

```
biplot.psych2<-biplot.psych
body(biplot.psych2)[[11]][[3]][[12]]<-NULL
```

And then call our new function with

```
biplot.psych2(fa2,pch=c(24,21)[bfi[1:100,"gender"]],
    bg=c("blue","red")[bfi[1:100,"gender"]],
    main="Biplot of Conscientiousness and Neuroticism by gender")
```

to get

[image]

Comment: Many Thanks.. is there any ways to get rid of those red letters and numbers as well?

Comment: You can set `body(biplot.psych)[[c(11,3)]][11:12]<-NULL` instead to get rid of them both

Answer (score 0):

Months after you posted your question, here is a quick answer.  What you are actually asking for is not a biplot (which includes the factor scores as well as the factor loadings), but just a plot of the factor scores.  Using your example, just

plot(fa2$scores,bg=c("blue","red")[bfi[1:100,"gender"]],pch=c(24,21)[bfi[1:100,"gender"]],ylim=c(-3,3),xlim=c(-3,3)).